# Probability a ball will stay in urn forever

Tags: probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Suppose that there is an urn with infinite capacity. In the first day, we put one ball in the urn and remove it. In the second day, we put 2 balls and remove one randomly. in the $k^{th}$-day, we put $k$ balls and remove one randomly.

What is the probability that, eventually, we will put a ball and never remove it.

Well, first, it's not hard to see that before removing a ball, in the $k^{th}$ day there are:

$$\frac{k(k+1)}{2}-(k-1)=\frac{k(k-1)}{2}+1$$

Now, let's focus on some ball from the $N^{th}$ day, and for every $n\geq N$, let $A_n$ is the event a ball that was inserted in the $N^{th}$ day will be removed by, at most, the $n^{th}$ day. So $A_N\subseteq A_{N+1}\subseteq\cdots$ and the event that a ball from the $N^{th}$ will stay in the urn forever is:

$$B_N=\bigcap_{n=N}^\infty A_n^C$$

also, we get that:

$$P(A_{n+1}|A_n^C)=\frac{1}{\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+1}$$

Therefore, $\sum_{n=N}^\infty P(A_{n+1}|A_n^C)<\infty$

Those are just ideas, I don't really know how to proceed  from here...

Comment: You cannot reasonably choose a "random natural number" , at least not if every number must have the same chance to be picked up. And even more problematic is to repeat this infinite many often with more and more numbers. We could argue that after every step, we removed finite many balls, so the chance that the given ball vanished , is $0$. But that does not mean that it is impossible that the ball vanished. I think, the exercise is ill-posed.

Comment: @Peter Based on your comment, I disagree that the problem is ill-posed.  The question seems unambiguous to me, with the understanding that if there is a ball that never leaves the urn, the ball might have been placed there at any time.  By the OP's own admission, his analysis, which is a reasonable try at showing work, does not answer the question.  Stating that the question is ill-posed indicates to me that you think that either the question is ambiguous, the question involves math that no one will ever be able to answer, or the question is not a math question.

Comment: Isn't this probability equal to 1? After each turn you have more balls in the urn than before. In other words, after n-th turn you have a ball (in fact, many of them) who were not removed in previous turns. Even if $n$ tends to infinity, you have more and more such balls. It's a completely different issue if a specific ball will stay in the urn forever, but your formulation is different.

Comment: @Oldboy I think that you have to focus on one specific ball each time, and find the probability that it will stay in the urn forever

Comment: @TairGalili I question whether your interpretation is consistent with the OP's : "I am trying to calculate the probability that there is a ball that will stay inside the urn forever."  As I interpret it, the OP is not asking about any one specific ball.  In other words, as I interpret it, the OP is asking for $(1 - p)$, where $p$ is the probability that every ball placed in the urn eventually comes out.

Comment: @TairGalili Even if you now agree with me, it could well be that the OP's *intent* is as you initially interpreted it.  However, in that event, I question why the OP would not specify something like: assume that the ball is placed on turn $K$, where $K$ is some fixed positive integer $> 1.$

Comment: @user2661923: Hmm, your options are not exhaustive. The problem may be ill-posed in the sense that the desired probability might not be well-defined. Although it turns out to be well-defined here (countable union of events in a suitable probability space), it isn't obvious, and presumably the asker didn't even realize the potential issue...

Comment: @user2661923 I have rephrased the question, hope it makes more sense now

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the chance of survival of a ball present on day $n\gg0$ should be $\approx e^{-2/(n-1)}$?

Comment: "What is the probability that, eventually, we will put a ball and never remove it." : Yes, in my opinion, this clarifies the question.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Can you explain why?

Comment: The probability any of the three remaining after day 3 will stay forever can be found by inclusion-exclusion as $3q_{3,1}-3q_{3,2}+q_{3,3}$.  Here $q_{3,1}=\prod (n^2+n)/(n^2+n+2)$, $q_{3,2}=\prod (n^2+n-2)/(n^2+n+2)$ and $q_{3,3}=\prod (n^2+n-4)/(n^2+n+2)$

Comment: Software tells me the probability in my previous comment is $(8\pi+4\cos(\pi\sqrt{17/4}))/\cosh(\pi\sqrt{7/4})\approx0.91$

Comment: My calculations for at least one of the six balls after day 4 to remain forever came to a probability of $0.9984429539$